# is there lastInsertId() for non-primary key? Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am getting Trying to get property of non-object  error in `$routine = $routine->getRoutine($event->routine_id);` because of `$event->routine_id` 
But it is kinda weird because when I do `var_dump($event)` `$event->routine_id` actually has a value in it and now look at my `getEventsbydate` function     However I had the same error last time so I try to use `$this->routine_id = $this->_connection->lastInsertId();` to manually send routine_id but since routine_id is not a primary key of the table it fails is there any function that can send column which is not primary key?

```
public function getEventsbydate($year, $month, $day)
{

    $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM event WHERE year = :year AND month = :month AND day = :day");


    $stmt->execute(['year'=>$year,'month'=>$month, 'day'=>$day]);
    $this->routine_id = $this->_connection->lastInsertId();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Event_model"); //datatype user
    return $stmt->fetchAll(); 
}

public function index($y, $m, $d){

    $event = $this->model('Event_model');
    $event = $event->getEventsbydate($y, $m, $d);


    $routine = $this->model('Routine_model'); 
    $routine = $routine->getRoutine($event->routine_id);


    if($event == false){ //if there is nothing in the workout_list

        header("location:/Event/create/$y/$m/$d"); //mylist controller , create method
    }
    else{
        //whatever you would do here
        $this->view('routine/routine_index',$routine);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns auto_increment value for last **inserted** row.

You're not performing an `INSERT`.

You're performing a `SELECT`.

Comment: Yeah but I tried to use last_insert_id() to returns primary key because it says $event->routine_id  is a non-object and someone said that execute() doesn't send values right away so that's why even though $event has values , it says non-object

Comment: So what I want to do is that I just want to get $event->routine_id     would there be a way to get this value?

Comment: I don't know what you have imagined, but you can't perform a select and expect that `lastInsertId` gives some kind of value you *want*. Your select probably produces more than one row. Which primary key are you after? First row? Last row? Middle row? Consider taking a pause and explaining *what* you're after, then we can tell you *how* to get it.

Comment: You are right Thank you so much! I thought it was insert into